# Linux backup service with Glacier support

Tags: linux, backup, amazon-glacier

I`m using bacula + s3fs to make backups on S3 but it doesn`t support Glacier. Is there something like Bacula with Glacier support?

I need

- different backup polices (FULL,INCREMENTAL ... e.t.c.)
- edit backup jobs from single place
- monitoring of backup job status

P.S. Backup of remoted servers will be good :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question appears to be [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Especially if you expect:

- A software recommendation
- A completed software solution

Your question would receive more attention on: [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com)

---

I recommend to use bacula because:

- You're obviously already familiar with it
- It supports your requirements
- It supports additional encryption which is recommended to store your data on aws

We are using a python script wich get fired periodically using cron. 
You may run the script also after any job using [RunScript](http://www.bacula.org/5.2.x-manuals/en/main/main/Configuring_Director.html#7438).

The main concept is to [use each volume once](http://www.bacula.org/5.2.x-manuals/en/main/main/Configuring_Director.html#9625). After the desired volumes are marked as used, upload them to amazon glacier.

Our script does:

1. Fetch the PoolId's of the desired Pools from `bacula.Pools`. We only upload full backups.
2. Fetch MediaId's from `Media`  with `VolStatus=Used` and `PoolId` is one of the previous
3. Write MediaId's to a new table (eq: `MediaArchive`) wich keeps the state of processed glacier uploads.
4. Upload the file `Media.VolumeName` using [boto](https://github.com/boto/boto) ([create_archive_from_file](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/glacier.html#boto.glacier.vault.Vault.create_archive_from_file))
5. On success, save the archive id to your `MediaArchive`. Otherwise restart the upload.